# Java Number with '_' sign

Tags: java

why does Java numbers allow you to write with the '_' sign?
what is this plus? does not complicate the language?

```
int a= 1_23_4_5_6;
double b=34_3.2_3;
float f=34_3_4.2_3f;
```

EDIT:Yes, i think '_' sign is good for 1_000_000, but for 34_3_4.2_3f or 34_3.2_3? i think that really complicate.

Comment: For convience, to make things more readable. For example: `10000000` vs `10_000_000`. From the latter you immediately see it's 10 million, but with the former you have to count the zeroes to be sure. Of course it isn't useful if you put the underscores in arbitrary locations, as you did in your examples.

Comment: It just help you to split the number like `1_000_000`. You can easily find it's 1 million without count the zeros.

Comment: i wanted to ask why allow  34_3_4.2_3f ,34_3.2_3 and other. Yes, i think '_ ' sign is good for 1_000_000, but  for  34_3_4.2_3f or 34_3.2_3? i think that really complicate.

Comment: @HəsənCəfərov because you may not only want to separate the thousand-positions. You could, for example, separate octetts in an IPv4 address, written in binary: `0b00000000_11111111_11110000_00001111`. Instead of limiting the use cases language-wise it is easier to allow the global use of `_` and trust that it is only used in a meaningful way.

Comment: Just to give the corresponding JLS reference: [§3.10.1: "*\[...\] Underscores are allowed as separators between digits that denote the integer. \[...\]*"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

Comment: In addition to @Turing85’s nice example, I also prefer to group digits of hex numbers in groups of two or four rather than three. It would have been really complicated to make a rule about which groupings should be allowed and which should be forbidden. And feel free to write your own checker to check that digits are grouped according to your preferences.

Comment: Did you read the docs before asking? That’s always a good idea.

Comment: They trusted us to make sensible groups without it being imposed. I agree that `34_3_4.2_3f` and `34_3.2_3` are really bad, If I saw one of those in a code review, I would ask the programmer to change them. Fortunately that’s perfectly possible without the language forcing us to do it.

Comment: Java (and high-level languages in general) is there to allow for the writing of readable and simple code, not to prevent the writing of unreadable code. `_` is there to allow things like `1_000_000` - prevent programmers from abusing that is the job of those programmers, not Java. One can also use `10/5/2` instead of using the constant `1` for roughly the same reason.

Answer (score 6):

It's a [Java 7 addition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) that allows you to group numbers if you so wish.

For example instead of writing

```
int i = 1000000000;
```

you can write the much more readable version

```
int i = 1_000_000_000;
```

Answer (score 5):

From [Underscores in Numeric Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) :

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can
>   appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal.
>
> This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in
>   numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Note: from Oracle [Java SE 7 Specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html)

```
long creditCardNumber = 1234_5678_9012_3456L;
long socialSecurityNumber = 999_99_9999L;
float pi =  3.14_15F;
long hexBytes = 0xFF_EC_DE_5E;
long hexWords = 0xCAFE_BABE;
long maxLong = 0x7fff_ffff_ffff_ffffL;
byte nybbles = 0b0010_0101;
long bytes = 0b11010010_01101001_10010100_10010010;
```

Now what say, does it complex the readability or it's way easier to make the code readable.

In real application, at point of debug/failure, this can avoid the ambiguity and help developers to search for the right culprit more easily.